# capybaraを用いて、redirect先のページを検証する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

capybaraを使って、フィーチャースペックを書いています。

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to new_user_path
  end

  def new
    # do something
  end
end
```

というコントローラーがあったとして、

```
    feature "サンプルフィーチャー", :type => :feature do
      scenario "新規ユーザー作成画面へ遷移する" do
        visit users_path
        expect(current_path).to eq new_user_path
      end
    end
```

上のように、なんらかのイベント後にredirect先のページにリダイレクトされているかを検証したいのですが、何か方法はありますか？？

Answer (score 1):

以下のようなexampleを書けばいいと思います。
visitのところを好きなクリックしたら移動するようなメソッドに変えると望んだことが出来ると思います。

```
feature "サンプルフィーチャー", :type => :feature do
  scenario "新規ユーザー作成画面へ遷移する" do
   visit users_path
   expect{ visit new_user_path }.to change {
     current_path
   }.from(users_path).to(users_path)
  end
end
```